# Copy worksheet from another work book by loop

Tags: excel

```
For Each ws In punchcalc.Worksheets
    ws.Range("D11:L33").Copy
    reportfile.Activate
    reportfile.Sheets(Index).Range("D11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Index = Index + 1
    Next ws
End Sub
```

this code working only one second loop getting an error

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have provided incomplete information. Your code is incomplete. Also it has only one loop so are you running it more than once? What is the error? On which line do you get this error? Edit your post to include such relevant details.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code, as well as a better description of the issue and what you're trying to achieve ?   On a first look: you will always paste your new range into D11, thereby overwriting what was in there before.

Comment: You can check this link, it would be helpfull https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code provide some guidelines on how you can act. So modify the code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    'Let us assume that you run the code from another workbook (NOT wbSource or wbDestination) & both workbooks are closed. At the end of the code you can close the workbooks if you want to.
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\Source") 'Open wbSource
    Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Open("C:\x\xx\xx\xx\Destination") 'Open wbDestination

    For Each ws In wbSource.Worksheets 'Loop wbSource Sheet1

        With wbDestination.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find wbDestination, Sheet1 Last row
        End With

        ws.Range("A1").Copy wbDestination.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Lastrow + 1) 'Paste wbSource.ws.Range("A1").value to wbDestination.Sheet1.Range("A" & Lastrow + 1)

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use select

```
    For Each ws In punchcalc.Worksheets
      ws.Range("D11:L33").Copy
      reportfile.Sheets(Index).Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Index = Index + 1
    Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.